# Variable value does not change? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

So I try to put a variable into a labels x... so that when the variable changes the label starts to move.

But the problem is that the variable does not change it's value, but stays at "0" when I press the button 'Next'

Need help please:

```
import tkinter as tk

from docx import Document

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 600

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

nextt=tk.IntVar()
nextt=0 #setup the nextt variable

label1 = tk.Label(text='example:')
label1.place(x=90+nextt,y=50) #put the variable here to affect position

def next2():
    nextt=300

button2 = tk.Button(text="Next", font=40, command=next2)
button2.place(x=230, y=440) 
#when pressing this button,variable nextt should change to 300, but it doesnt

root.mainloop()
```

I have already tried with nextt.set=300, and/or nextt.get(), all possible combinations...

Comment: Your `next2` function doesn't do anything except assign to a local variable.

Comment: Inside the `next2()` function, the `nextt` variable is local.  It has no connection to the outer variable of the same name.

Comment: Ok.. How do I connect it with the variable in the x value?

Answer (score 0):

`nextt` in the function `next2` is a local variable, you could try placing the label inside the function instead:

```
def next2():
    label1.place(x = 390, y = 50)
```

If you want to `place` it later, then use `nextt` as a global variable (not a very nice solution btw):

```
def next2():
    global nextt
    nextt = 300
# more code
# ...
label1.place(x = 90 + nextt, y = 50)
```

Just changing `nextt` will not automatically place the label, you have to do it again at some other place in the code.

Comment: Ok... global did not work, and placing label in definition woun't work either... Is there not any other solution on pressing a button to make something move?

Comment: @Selfiatus1 Do you want it to move just one time? Or every time you press the button?